# Show VAT on specific customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, price, customer-group, vat

I have two customer groups
Retailers and wholesalers.
The retailers showing prices with VAT
Is it possible for the wholesale group to show their prices whithout the VAT and show it only in cart?
The prices for those 2 groups are not the same
Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Without custom coding, I don't think there is an option.

The easiest way would be using a [Plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for [getPriceDisplayType()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/02e1c6b65eae87e9b47521b99bd3ef72703afe71/app/code/Magento/Tax/Model/Config.php) method and return **\Magento\Tax\Model\Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_BOTH** when you need it based on cutomer group.

Comment: Plugins are not an option in Magneto 1.9.2

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Then this should be the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532650/magento-showing-prices-ex-inc-tax-vat-depending-on-customer-group

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this by configuration.

You will need to modify .phtml files to handle this but this should not be very complex.